# I cant seem to get jquery $.post to work

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).click(function(){
    getComments();
});

function getComments()
{
    var directory = $(".active img").prop("src");
    directory = directory.substring(58);
    //alert(directory);
    $("#photoComments").text(directory);
    $.post('getPhotoComments.php', function(output){
        //$("#photoComments").html(output);
        $("#photoComments").html("jus checkin2").show();
    });
}
```

Above is my code. Everything works until the part where I start $.post. Nothing in the function() works. I am just testing to see if it would set my id #photoComments to the provided text: "jus checkin 2" but nothing seems to happen. Please I really need  help with that. And yeah I have the url "getPhotoComments.php" set up properly and its not being used yet. Thanks

Comment: You mean the code inside the callback doesn't run, or it runs but the "just checking" thing doesn't show?

Comment: Any Error messages? Anything from Firebug( or similar )? I think we need more to help you.

Comment: can you show you getPhotoComments.php and also if you are not posting anything to the file then use get...

Comment: Are you able to  access `getPhotoComments.php` manually? Does it work?

Comment: Sorry but what I meant was the code insiode the callback didn't work. I appreciate your help guys but suddenly all seems to work, seems my servers been a bit slow, so files dont get updated instantly. But anyways thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evra: Try to put it into

```
$(function(){
    //your code
});
```

Comment: Thanks genesis but I saw somewhere that if you put your jquery javascript code in the body tag and not the head, then its not necessary to put it in the function openeing and closing bracket. Correct me if I'm wrong but I am just asking.